# creating alert to the selected user upon register

Tags: php, notifications, alert

I am setting up a online clinic registration system using PHP. The system has two different groups of user that is the patient and the clinics. The patient will choose from the available clinics and upon registration, the patient will be issued with a unique queue number. I already did all these but what I need to know now how do I create an alert to the clinic's user when they receive a new registration from a patient user?This alert is to notify the clinics of the new registration without refreshing the webpage.

Comment: You will probably need to use ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax to fetch latest(or unread) notifications from the server. This Ajax can be sent periodically from the browser of a logged in clinic user.
You can also email the clinic if it is not online.

Answer (score 0):

I would use "XMLHttpRequest" to do this.  On the clinic's webpage I would have the javascript something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var comm = new Array(), frameTime = 0, regTime = 0;

function startItUp(){
    animate();
}

window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){//from Paul Irish
    return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
    function(callback, element){
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();
function animate() {
    frameTime = Date.now();
        if(regTime < frameTime){
            comm.push( new getRegistrants() );
            regTime = frameTime + 8000;//how often to call the php page and check for new patients
        }
    }
    requestAnimFrame( animate );
}
function getRegistrants(){
    this.client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    this.client.onload  = function () {
        var registrantData = this.responseText;
        //Parse the registrant data displayed by php page here and make the alert or div popup...
        alert(parsedRegistrantName + ' has registered.');

    }
    this.client.open('POST', 'getRegistrants.php');//This page would have a session that would contain your logged in clinic's ID and would just output registrant(patient) data that you can parse
    this.client.send();
}
</script>
```

Then in clinic's webpage to start it:

```
<body onload="startItUp();">
```

NOTE: This method has worked fine for me in several web appliations but, from my personal experience, if you have many clinics(several hundred say) executing the XMLHttpRequest then you will run into a server resource issue if you have cheap/common shared hosting for this.